# Is there any way to run WorkManager's requests non-persistently?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I've switched to WorkManager and use it in almost all cases. Methods, that return LiveData by request ID, are very convenient for UI-binding.

I have a task to log in to a remote server. So, I would like to keep on using WorkManagers API for this task but do not need total DB-level persistence. I need keeping track of my task only in app lifecycle (e.x. during orientation changes) and, of cause, no posting my credentials to service DB.

Is there any way to enqueue and keep track if my background tasks in WorkManager manner but with no persistence, just for running process?

OK, I implemented my own small WorkManager based on WorkManager's classes but it's quite hard to support.

```
static class ThreadWorkManager extends TinyWorkManager {

        static final String TAG = ThreadWorkManager.class.getSimpleName();

        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        final Executor uiExecutor = Utils::uiPost;
        final HashMap<UUID, WorkData> workDatum = new HashMap<>();
        final WeakHashMap<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, UUID> liveIdDatum = new WeakHashMap<>();
        final WeakHashMap<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, String> liveTagDatum = new WeakHashMap<>();

        static WorkInfo fromWorkData(UUID id, WorkData workData) {
            return workData != null ? new WorkInfo(id, workData.spec.state, workData.spec.output, workData.tagList) : null;
        }

        static class WorkData {
            final ListenableWorker worker;
            final WorkSpec spec;
            final Set<String> tags;
            final List<String> tagList;
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Runnable startLater;

            WorkData(ListenableWorker worker, WorkSpec spec) {
                this.worker = worker;
                this.spec = spec;
                this.tags = worker.getTags();
                this.tagList = new ArrayList<>(tags);
            }
        }

        void onWorkChanged(UUID id) {
            //if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Thread.currentThread() != ui.getLooper().getThread())
            //  throw new AssertionError();

            WorkData workData = workDatum.get(id);
            if (workData == null) return;

            workData.time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            WorkInfo workInfo = fromWorkData(id, workData);

            //TODO remove finished workdata and id livedata

            while (true) {
                try {
                    for (Map.Entry<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, UUID> entry : liveIdDatum.entrySet())
                        if (entry.getValue().equals(id))
                            entry.getKey().setValue(workInfo);
                    break;
                } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "concurrent 1");
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                try {
                    for (Map.Entry<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, String> entry : liveTagDatum.entrySet())
                        if (workData.tags.contains(entry.getValue()))
                            entry.getKey().setValue(workInfo);
                    break;
                } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "concurrent 2");
                }
            }
        }

        void scheduleWork(UUID id, WorkData workData, long delay) {
            workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;

            onWorkChanged(id);

            uiPost(workData.startLater = () -> {
                workData.startLater = null;

                workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.RUNNING;

                onWorkChanged(id);

                ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> future = workData.worker.startWork();
                future.addListener(new WorkerListener(id, future), uiExecutor);
            }, delay);
        }

        @Override
        public void enqueue(WorkRequest workRequest) {
            //executor.submit(new WorkUnit(workRequest));

            try {
                Class<? extends ListenableWorker> workerClass = (Class<? extends ListenableWorker>) Class.forName(workRequest.getWorkSpec().workerClassName);
                Class[] types = {Context.class, WorkerParameters.class};
                Constructor constructor = workerClass.getConstructor(types);

                UUID id = workRequest.getId();
                WorkSpec workSpec = workRequest.getWorkSpec();

                ListenableWorker worker = (ListenableWorker) constructor.newInstance(appContext, new WorkerParameters(
                        id,
                        workSpec.input,
                        workRequest.getTags(),
                        null,
                        workSpec.runAttemptCount,
                        executor,
                        null,
                        null));

                WorkData workData = new WorkData(worker, workRequest.getWorkSpec());
                workDatum.put(worker.getId(), workData);

                if (workSpec.initialDelay > 0) {
                    scheduleWork(id, workData, workSpec.initialDelay);
                } else {
                    workSpec.state = WorkInfo.State.RUNNING;

                    onWorkChanged(id);

                    ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> future = worker.startWork();
                    future.addListener(new WorkerListener(worker.getId(), future), uiExecutor);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        class WorkerListener implements Runnable {

            private final UUID id;
            private final ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> future;

            WorkerListener(UUID id, ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> future) {
                this.id = id;
                this.future = future;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                WorkData workData = workDatum.get(id);
                if (workData == null) return;

                try {
                    ListenableWorker.Result r = future.get();
                    if (r == null || r instanceof ListenableWorker.Result.Failure) {
                        workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.FAILED;
                        if (r != null)
                            workData.spec.output = ((ListenableWorker.Result.Failure) r).getOutputData();

                        onWorkChanged(workData.worker.getId());
                    } else if (r instanceof ListenableWorker.Result.Success) {
                        workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED;
                        workData.spec.output = ((ListenableWorker.Result.Success) r).getOutputData();

                        onWorkChanged(id);

                        if(workData.spec.isPeriodic())
                            scheduleWork(id, workData, workData.spec.intervalDuration);
                    } else if (r instanceof ListenableWorker.Result.Retry) {
                        workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;

                        onWorkChanged(id);

                        //TODO spec.backoffPolicy
                        scheduleWork(id, workData, workData.spec.backoffDelayDuration);
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, workData.worker.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + id + " " + workData.spec.state);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, workData.worker.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + id + " no future");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public WorkInfo getWorkInfo(String tag) {
            WorkData tagWorkData = null;
            for (WorkData workData : workDatum.values())
                if (workData.tags.contains(tag) && (tagWorkData == null || tagWorkData.time < workData.time))
                    tagWorkData = workData;

            return tagWorkData != null ? fromWorkData(UUID.fromString(tagWorkData.spec.id), tagWorkData) : null;
        }

        @Override
        public LiveData<WorkInfo> getWorkInfoLiveData(UUID id) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Thread.currentThread() != ui.getLooper().getThread())
                throw new AssertionError();

            MutableLiveData<WorkInfo> liveData = null;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    for (Map.Entry<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, UUID> entry : liveIdDatum.entrySet())
                        if (entry.getValue().equals(id)) {
                            liveData = entry.getKey();

                            break;
                        }
                    break;
                } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "concurrent 3");
                }
            }

            if (liveData == null) {
                liveIdDatum.put(liveData = new MutableLiveData<>(), id);

                WorkInfo workInfo = fromWorkData(id, workDatum.get(id));
                if (workInfo != null)
                    liveData.setValue(workInfo);
            }

            return liveData;
        }

        @Override
        public LiveData<WorkInfo> getWorkInfoLiveData(String tag) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Thread.currentThread() != ui.getLooper().getThread())
                throw new AssertionError();

            MutableLiveData<WorkInfo> liveData = null;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    for (Map.Entry<MutableLiveData<WorkInfo>, String> entry : liveTagDatum.entrySet())
                        if (entry.getValue().equals(tag)) {
                            liveData = entry.getKey();

                            break;
                        }
                    break;
                } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "concurrent 4");
                }
            }

            if (liveData == null) {
                liveTagDatum.put(liveData = new MutableLiveData<>(), tag);

                WorkInfo workInfo = getWorkInfo(tag);
                if (workInfo != null)
                    liveData.setValue(workInfo);
            }

            return liveData;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelWork(UUID id) {
            WorkData workData = workDatum.get(id);
            if (workData != null && !workData.spec.state.isFinished()) {
                if (workData.startLater != null) {
                    uiRemove(workData.startLater);
                    workData.startLater = null;
                }

                workData.worker.stop();

                workData.spec.state = WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED;

                onWorkChanged(id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelWork(String tag) {
            for (WorkData workData : workDatum.values())
                if (workData.tags.contains(tag))
                    cancelWork(UUID.fromString(workData.spec.id));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using WorkManager if you don't need the tasks to persist.  You should, instead, find a different solution as per the Background Processing Guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

Comment: Could you advice mature library for background processing with Unit of Work pattern implementation and features like LiveData referencing task state?